# Stack Overflow data dumpのPostTypeId=1,2以外は何を表すのでしょうか？

Tags: サポート, data-dump

Stack Overflow data dumpを使っているのですが，その使い方等を書いているreadmeファイルのPosts.xmlの説明の部分で以下のようなことが書かれています．

- **posts**.xml

  - Id
  - PostTypeId

    - 1: Question
    - 2: Answer
  - ParentID (only present if PostTypeId is 2)
  - AcceptedAnswerId (only present if PostTypeId is 1)

調べてみたところ，PostTypeIdが1と2以外に7までありました．
PostTypeId="3"からPostTypeId="7"は何をあらわしているのでしょうか？

Answer (score 5, accepted):

PostTypeId の値は PostTypes テーブルで定義されています。この中身を見るには、SEDE の Database Schema パネルを使うと簡単です。

1. http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/new にアクセス
2. 右側の Database Schema パネルに注目。初期状態ではテーブルが全て展開されているので、右上にある「－」（マイナス）をクリックして折りたたむ
3. 一覧をスクロールして、PostTypes の右側にある「i」をクリック
4. すると以下のように表示されます

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]